# dpkg: error processing archive

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I got this error when trying to install anything on ubuntu 16.04.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-
samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-libxml2_2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.6_amd64.deb
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried apt-get -f install but it shows the same error . could anyone help ?

Comment: After a while in searching , i have fixed the problem with those lines in terminal :-

Comment: sudo apt-get clean

Comment: sudo apt-get update

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal  python-lockfile

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a while in searching , i have fixed the problem with those lines in terminal:

```
 $ sudo apt-get clean
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal python-lockfile
 $ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: There is no explanation and just lines of code. Obviously this did not work. 
`apt-get update` gives the error, and the answer includes running `apt-get update`. How is that useful?

Answer (score 4):

For a generic approach on how to deal with the issue stated in this question's header, also check [answers of this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in/433510#433510)

the following fixed my issue

```
sudo dpkg -P <program>
```

Comment: I have warning "ignoring request to remove npm which isn't installed"

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, please check your Python versions.

Insert command:

```
update-alternatives --config python
```

[image]

Then enable version 2.7.

Now check.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the old package and continue the installation this way:

```
dpkg -r libsgutils2-2
apt-get --fix-broken install
apt-get dist-upgrade
```